# Laravel Consolestvs\charts - Displaying data belonging to specific user whos logged in, in a chart

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm using Laravels Consoletvs\charts to generate charts for my project. I'm trying to get the chart to only display the "question" created by a specific user, currently it just displays all the "questions" that are in the database, but I'm unsure on how to write the string for this, basically I need it to only show the "question" that match the id of the user that is currently logged in.

Any help is much appreciated :)

My chart controller is shown below

```
    $questions = Question::where(DB::raw("(DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y'))"),date('Y'))
                ->get();
    $questionChart = Charts::database($questions, 'bar', 'highcharts')
              ->title("Questions Assigned")
              ->elementLabel("Total Questions")
              ->dimensions(1000, 500)
              ->responsive(true)
              ->groupByMonth(date('Y'), true);


    return view('welcome', compact('userChart', 'testChart', 'questionChart'));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong then *you want to display the questions created by the logged in user*.

To get a solution you must have a relation predefined between the questions and users table.

I'm assuming that you have a **user_id** column in your *Question Model*

$loggedin_user_id = 'some_id';

Try this

```
$questions = Question::where('user_id', $loggedin_user_id)
                ->get();
```